# Intellij-IDEA gradle templates

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, build.gradle

How can I change the template of "build.gradle" in IntelliJ IDEA 15.0.1 ?

I'd like to delete "sourceCompatibility", to add 'idea' plugin, and to modify the version of JUnit.

I'd tried to modify "Gradle Build Script" as below,

Perference > Editor > File and Code Templates > Gradle Build Script

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

but I got a build.gradle as followed

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.5

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
}
```

Best Regards,

-Mitsutaka Ohisa

Comment: Have you made progress with this? I was researching this as well - it seems that the template in the settings is not the full template used in the Gradle Project generator. This is very poorly documented by Jetbrains!

Answer (score 0):

The preferences you are interest are hard-coded in IDEA JetBrains gradle plugin:

`<IDEA_base>\plugins\gradle\lib\gradle.jar\org\jetbrains\plugins\gradle\frameworkSupport\GradleJavaFrameworkSupportProvider.class`